# Link to date_query results in Wordpress

Tags: posts, wp-query, links

I have this line of code:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2015',
            'before'    => 'February 15th, 2015',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This code will return all the post published between Jan 1st and Feb 15th. 
My question is can I somehow create a link to the results of this query?

For example I can go to

```
localhost/wordpress?monthnum=1
```

and get all posts from January, but is there a link, or can I create custom link that will accept the parameters of my date_query, so I can display all the posts that match my query?

Basically I just want to show all posts published between specific dates on a separate page, and I want a link to that page, but I don't know if such thing is possible.

Just to be clear, I just want to know is there a link such as:

```
localhost/wordpress?after=January1st2015&before=February15th2015
```

available in Wordpress so I can quickly access the query results, or is there a way to create such a link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $_GET to get the query string values and then pass it in the $args to create a dynamic WP_Query

```
$after = $_GET['after'];
$before = $_GET['before'];
```

and then in the $args

```
if ($after && $before) {
    $args = array(
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after'     => $after,
                'before'    => $before,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ),
        ),
    );
} else {
    // default args
}
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```